# Convert GUID into Byte array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, guid

I need to convert a system-generated GUID into a Byte[16] array and then convert those decimal values into a hex value string.  Crazy, I know and I'm very open to a more efficient approach than the ones I've tried!

I've tried PHPs unpack() function on this GUID but can't seem to get the right format.  I've tried c*, C* and all of the other possible formats.

Here's the GUID I'm starting with:

`GUID:  dwRhRSIjlGXhAAAAkuFQ0A`

The Byte[16] array I'm trying to populate should look like this:

```
$bytearray = array(119,4,97,69,34,35,-108,101,-31,0,0,0,-110,-31,80,-48);
```

Once I get this $bytearray value, I can easily use PHPs dechex() function to convert each of these decimal values into their corresponding hex values.  The end result of this conversion should look like this:

```
DEC: HEX
119: 77
4: 4
97: 61
69: 45
34: 22
35: 23
-108: 94
101: 65
-31: E1
0: 00
0: 00
0: 00
-110: 92
-31: E1
80: 50
-48: D0
```

Again, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really get what you want… You want an array with the hex value of the ASCCI code of the chars within you ID, am I right?

```
$str = "dwRhRSIjlGXhAAAAkuFQ0A";
$bytes = array();

for($i=0,$l = strlen($str);$i<$l;$i++)
{
    $bytes[] = dechex(ord($str[$i]));
}
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that the $str I am working with above is actually a base64 binary value.  I'm now investigating how to decode base64 into hex.

Comment: Your solution got me on the right track!  All I had to do was base64_decode the $str above to get text, then used your code to convert the text to hex.  Thanks again!