# How to convert MS generated GUID to byte array and byte array to GUID in PHP?

Tags: php

How to convert MS generated GUID to byte array and byte array to GUID in PHP?

Is there any predefined class for this in PHP?

An example for GUID is 9FA6DFE3-484C-4451-A552-781E23D0476F.

Comment: Define "MS generated GUID".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051734/convert-guid-into-byte-array-using-php

Comment: Define "byte array". Byte arrays are *strings* in PHP.

Comment: Anything wrong with the answer below? You've not answered the comments above, commented on the answer or marked as answer, which makes me wonder whether it solved your problem and if not - why not?

Answer (score 2):

Guids in that format are somewhat tricky to convert since their byte order is not the same as in the display format. A translation table makes it fairly straight forward though;

```
function guid_to_bytes($guid) {
  $guid_byte_order = [3,2,1,0,5,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
  $guid = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $guid);
  $result = [];
  for($i=0;$i<16;$i++)
    $result[] = hexdec(substr($guid, 2 * $guid_byte_order[$i], 2));
  return $result;
}

function bytes_to_guid($bytes) {
  $guid_byte_order = [3,2,1,0,5,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
  $result = "";
  for($i=0;$i<16;$i++)
    $result = sprintf($result."%02x", $bytes[$guid_byte_order[$i]]);
  return $result;
}
```

Note that this converts the guid to an integer array with unsigned byte values, not strictly a byte array, and that the string representation does not insert dashes, that you'll have to add if you need it.

[An IDEone for testing](http://ideone.com/GNmc4l).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the `$guid_byte_order` the bytes 6 and 7 should be swapped; The correct order is `[3,2,1,0,5,4,7,6,8,9,10,...`